# Combobox initialized within a [Kendo UI] ListView template

Tags: listview, drop-down-menu, kendo-ui

I have a [Kendo] ListView in a [razor] view. I have a drop down as part of the ListView template. I can get the drop down loaded with an enumeration list and can bind to the onchange event. What is  not happening is the combo box is  not being initialized with the specified value in the bound data object [to each row of the list view].

My ListView template is as such.

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="GroupUserMappingTemplate"> 

  <div>        
     @Html.DropDownList(
        "AccessLevel", 
        new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(P3X_DataAccess.Models.AccessLevel))), 
        new { 
             onchange = "(AccessLevelChanged(this));"
            }                    
    )
  </div>            
</script>
```

The property the combo box is initialized to is called AccessLevel. It is the name of the property that is in the object that is bound to the List View rows, and I assume is valid for use as the bound property. The binding does not occur (but no errors occur either).

Peter

Comment: Ok - it seems this question has people stumped. Maybe as a corollary question -- is there a initialization event I canohook into for a dropdown control

Peter

Comment: Ok; I bugged Telerik about this one and they recommended using a Kendo UI dropdown control. This control provides the ability to initialize the drop down.

Answer (score 0):

I used the edit event on the list view to initialize dropdowns.